# How can I save parent and child objects at the same time in Rails without using nested parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have objects with a parent-child relationship in a Rails 6 application:

```
class Sequence < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :frames, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
  belongs_to :sequence_list
end

class Frame < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sequence
end
```

In sequences_controller.rb, I want to create a Sequence and also a bunch of child Frames in the same controller action.

Here is the sequences_controller create action:

```
  # POST /sequences
  # POST /sequences.json
  def create
    #@sequence = Sequence.new(sequence_params)
    @sequence = Sequence.new
    @sequence.name = params[:sequence][:name]

    filename = params[:sequence][:upload][:file].original_filename
    tmp_filename = params[:sequence][:upload][:file].tempfile

    if (File.extname(filename)==".txt")
      Frame.transaction do
        File.readlines(tmp_filename).each do |line|
          i = Frame.new
          i.url = line.strip
          i.sequence = @sequence
          i.save
        end
      end
    end
    tmp_filename.close
    tmp_filename.unlink

    respond_to do |format|
      if @sequence.save
        format.html { redirect_to @sequence, notice: 'Sequence was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @sequence }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @sequence.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

When I POST to this action, I get the following error:

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: frames.sequence_id
```

The error is coming from the line `i.save` in the `Frame.transaction` block.

I understand that this error is happening because `i.sequence` is not being assigned, because `@sequence` has not yet been saved.

I believe the common approach in this situation might be to create the child objects in one shot using nested parameters, but in this case, the parameters for the child aren't actually available in the `params[]` hash because I'm not sending them via JSON; I'm sending a text-file which is parsed by this controller action to produce a list of child objects.

The reason I'm sending a text-file (rather than doing this using a nested form) is because there are so many child-objects it would be tedious to create them manually through the browser. There are hundreds or thousands of child objects per parent, so parsing an upload seems like the obvious approach.

I guess one way to solve this would be to use Javascript to parse the text-file on the front end and built a nested form, but is it possible to solve this from the controller?

I've been doing some reading about `:inverse_of` and `:autosave` for some of the associations, but it's not clear to me what the default approach for this situation is. How can I simultaneously save the parent and children, while allowing roll-back on failure like a normal controller Create method, without parsing the text-file on the front end?

Comment: Why dont you want to use accept_nested_attributes, its just one command that you need to add in the model and things will become easy.Kindly explain.

Comment: @Milind accept_nested_attributes doesn't help in my situation because I'm not sending the child objects as nested params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the `Sequence` is not saved and you have it as a relationship in your database.

Now in order for your code to work, you `sequence` instance should be created before the others.

Fortunately, `ActiveRecord` handles this. Here's what you should do:

```
# POST /sequences
# POST /sequences.json
def create
  #@sequence = Sequence.new(sequence_params)
  @sequence = Sequence.new
  @sequence.name = params[:sequence][:name]

  filename = params[:sequence][:upload][:file].original_filename
  tmp_filename = params[:sequence][:upload][:file].tempfile

  if (File.extname(filename)==".txt")
    Frame.transaction do
      File.readlines(tmp_filename).each do |line|
        @sequence.frames.new(url: line.strip)
      end
    end
  end
  tmp_filename.close
  tmp_filename.unlink

  respond_to do |format|
    if @sequence.save
      format.html { redirect_to @sequence, notice: 'Sequence was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @sequence }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @sequence.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

What I did is that I initialized the frames of the sequence, and `ActiveRecord` will handle their creation when you save your `@sequence` model.

NB: your `Sequence` model should have `has_many :frames` of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
class Frame < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sequence, optional: true
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid setting the relationship as optional though to retain as many validations as possible. It felt wrong to be loosening that restriction just for some intermediate time in the creation process.